# mongodb $nearSphere performance issue with huge data(over 200w+)

Tags: mongodb

mongodb version is 2.6
the total records in the collection is over `200w`

details as below
 **collection table structure** as below:

```
{
"postid":NumberLong(97040),
"accountid":NumberLong(348670),
"location":{
"type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[
        112.56531,
        32.425657
    ]
},
"type":NumberLong(1),
"countspreads":NumberLong(6),
"countavailablespreads":NumberLong(6),
"timestamp":NumberLong(1428131578)
}
```

collection `index` is `2dsphere`:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "location" : "2dsphere"
    },
    "name" : "location_2dsphere",
    "ns" : "fly.postspreads",
    "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
},
```

** query command ** as below

```
db.example.find({"location":{"$nearSphere":{"$geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[113.547821,22.18648]},"$maxDistance":50000, "$minDistance":0}}}).explain()
```

**result**

```
{
    "cursor" : "S2NearCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 145255,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1290016,
    "nscanned" : 1290016,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1290016,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1290016,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 4087,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "server" : "DB-SH-01:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

the value of `$maxDistance` is too large for now， from the above result, we will find that the command was scanned over 100w+ records and cost 4087ms.

if we reduce the value of $maxDistance to `500`, new result as below：

```
{
    "cursor" : "S2NearCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 21445,
    "nscannedObjects" : 102965,
    "nscanned" : 102965,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 102965,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 102965,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 634,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "server" : "DB-SH-01:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

now the command was scanned over 10w+ records and cost 634ms,  the query speed is too slow too. even if i reduce the value of `$maxDistance` to `0.0001`, the scanned records over 8w+, and the time is about 600ms too.

the query time is unacceptable, but i didn't find where was wrong.

Comment: Using the `millis` from explain is not a good way to time a query. What query time is acceptable? What have you done to investigate what the bottleneck is? Have you used [mongostat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/) to monitor the performance of the server while running the query?

Comment: hm.. if we do not use `millis`, what should we use?

Comment: Yes, we used `mongostat` to monitor the server performance, there is no overload on server, we just used its 1% resource.  for now, some query will     cost more than 5 seconds, but we can only accept 0.2 seconds for each query.  we are using mongo 2.6 right now,  maybe the bottleneck is the lock level of mongodb, because we have high-frequency of write and read. frequency